# Switch enabled-property of lable with doubleClick-event

Tags: vb.net, label, eventhandler

I have a lable and I want it to switch its enabled-property when doubleclicking on it. The code I wrote only works in one direction: if the label is enabled I can set enabled=false by doubleclicking, but if the label is not enabled I can't set enabled=true by doubleclicking. Here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Label1_DoubleClick_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.DoubleClick
     If Me.Label1.Enabled = True Then
         Me.Label1.Enabled = False
     Else
         Me.Label1.Enabled = True
     End If
 End Sub
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of the Enabled property is to prevent user interaction with a control. You can emulate the behavior you're looking for in a couple of ways:

- Instead of disabling the control, manually change its appearance

  ```
  If (Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black) Then
      '"disable" control
      Label1.ForeColor = Color.Gray
  Else
      '"enable" control
      Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
  End If
  ```
- Overlay the label with a transparent panel. Receive the DoubleClick event on the panel, but enable/disable the label below.